# material-ui-docs site won't run Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-macros'

Tags: docker-compose, material-ui

no issues section available at GitHub material-ui-docs :(, so I try to ask here.
BTW seems weird to install outside container :/
when tried to install, got error:

```
error - ./pages/_app.js
mui-docs  | Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-macros'
mui-docs  | Require stack:
mui-docs  | - /home/node/material-ui-docs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js
mui-docs  | - /home/node/material-ui-docs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/code-frame.js
mui-docs  | - /home/node/material-ui-docs/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/wellknown-errors-plugin/parseScss.js
```

here is docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  svcMuiDocs:
    image: "node:17-slim"
    restart: always
    container_name: "mui-docs"
    #user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/material-ui-docs
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - "./:/home/node/material-ui-docs:rw"
    ports:
      - "8012:8012"

    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    command:
    - |
       yarn && yarn docs:dev --port=8012

    networks:
      - default


networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: svcBackend
```

site won't start

can anybody help please ?

AS.

Answer (score 0):

well, just blind shooting... replaced few words in docker-compose.yml to:

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  svcMuiDocs:
    image: "node:17-slim"
    restart: always
    container_name: "mui-docs"
    #user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/material-ui-docs
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - "./:/home/node/material-ui-docs:rw"
    ports:
      - "8012:8012"

    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    command:
    - |

       yarn --ignore-platform && yarn docs:dev --port=8012

    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: svcBackend
```

NODE_ENV=development

added --ignore-platform to yarn

and viola it works :)

AS.